# Insert into database after creating user

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, asp.net-membership

I am using [Altairis security providers](http://altairiswebsecurity.codeplex.com/) for a memebership and roles in my asp.net web application. For registration I use CreateUserWizard. And after the user is created I want to insert his username into another table called Profiles.

```
       HTML
    ------------
   <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="CreateUserWizard1" OnCreatedUser="CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser" ....... />
    
    
         VB
    ------------
        Protected Sub CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
            'Create profile 
            Dim connStr As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DeskriptivaConnectionString").ConnectionString.ToString()
            
            Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
                Try
                    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
                    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Profiles (UserName) VALUES (@UserName)"
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = CreateUserWizard1.UserName
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End Using
        End Sub
```

But when the registration is complete the username doesnt insert into the Profiles table and no error message display.
What should I do to make it working?

Answer (score 1):

You never execute the command. Try `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` after adding the parameter

If you need more info look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)